# Identify this set: brown and tan bricks and plates

Tags: set-identification

What set do these parts go to?
There is no bag number.[image]
Three different shades of Brown.
Two are 2x6 and one is 6x6

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

- 15397 Plate 3 x 3 cross in reddish brown,
- 30137 Brick 1 x 4 with log profile, and
- 3958 Plate 6 x 6 in reddish brown,

This is set "Bricks bricks bricks", either [10717](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10717-1) or [11717](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11717-1).

[image: Set 10717]